# Combining a string and searching for this variable under the name of the combined string. Need to get a link

Tags: python

result=int(input())

photo = photo_ + result

photo_1="https://i.imgur.com/9SUZgxM.png"

photo_2="https://i.imgur.com/9SUZgxM.png"

photo_3="https://i.imgur.com/9SUZgxM.png"

photo_4="https://i.imgur.com/LhlpaUm.png"

photo_5="https://i.imgur.com/vMictIO.png"

print(photo)

Combining a string and searching for this variable under the name of the combined string.

For example you will get "https://i.imgur.com/vMictIO.png"

Comment: i would recommend putting code in code blocks ```{language name}(python in your case) <- at the start then new  line and write your code and  ` ``(without the space) <- at the end after your code in a new line

Comment: Instead of variables named photo_1, photo_2 etc., better to use such values as keys in a dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `globals()` which will list all global variables in a dictionary and then you could just get the value of what you want(by accessing the dictionary using get or directly using key-based access "[]":

```py
result = int(input("Enter a number: "))

photo_name = "photo_" + str(result)

photo_1 = "https://i.imgur.com/9SUZgxM.png"
photo_2 = "https://i.imgur.com/9SUZgxM.png"
photo_3 = "https://i.imgur.com/9SUZgxM.png"
photo_4 = "https://i.imgur.com/LhlpaUm.png"
photo_5 = "https://i.imgur.com/vMictIO.png"

desired_photo = globals()[photo_name]

print(desired_photo)
```

Hope this helps :0

Global:

```json
{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x000001C8992E71D0>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__file__': 'file/path', '__cached__': None, 'result': 3, 'photo_name': 'photo_3', 'photo_1': 'https://i.imgur.com/9SUZgxM.png', 'photo_2': 'https://i.imgur.com/9SUZgxM.png', 'photo_3': 'https://i.imgur.com/9SUZgxM.png', 'photo_4': 'https://i.imgur.com/LhlpaUm.png', 'photo_5': 'https://i.imgur.com/vMictIO.png'}
```

Also alternatively you could have the photo variables in a dict in the first place it would make things easier but i understand if that isnt an option.

Comment: what str(result) is doing here is just turning your input into a string or you can remove the int() in the input field to make it a string but if you wanna have it like that we need to  do str() so that we can add photo_ to the input bec if its an integer it will throw an error bec you cant add a string and an int

Answer (score 1):

As @Caiden mentioned,
You can do this using a dictionary.

```
result = input() # we want string type for concatenation, so no need for converting to int

photo = 'photo_' + result

photo_data = {'photo_1': "https://i.imgur.com/9SUZgxM.png",
              'photo_2': "https://i.imgur.com/9SUZgxM.png",
              'photo_3': "https://i.imgur.com/9SUZgxM.png",
              'photo_4': "https://i.imgur.com/LhlpaUm.png",
              'photo_5': "https://i.imgur.com/vMictIO.png"}

print(photo_data[photo])
```

Comment: This doesn't work very well if the constructed photo name (key) doesn't exist

Comment: @Codist I agree. I have gone through your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use discrete variables. Use a dictionary like this:

```
photos = {
    "photo_1": "https://i.imgur.com/9SUZgxM.png",
    "photo_2": "https://i.imgur.com/9SUZgxM.png",
    "photo_3": "https://i.imgur.com/9SUZgxM.png",
    "photo_4": "https://i.imgur.com/LhlpaUm.png",
    "photo_5": "https://i.imgur.com/vMictIO.png",
}

pn = input("Enter photo number: ")
key = "photo_" + pn
print(photos.get(key, "Not found"))
```